# notice Undefined variable:"string" (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

hello guys I have a problem editing the file, I added previously the update option but the problem begins when I click the "edit option" and I get a error result

```
<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: UserName in 
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\CRUD\edit.php</b> on line <b>33</b><br />
```

I looked up into the line and according with, I checked the connection ans have not problem with that but is still showing the same error.

there is my connection

```
 <?php
require_once("conection.php");
$UserID = $_GET['GetID'];
$query = "select * from user where User_ID='".$UserID."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $UserID = $row['User_ID'];
    $UserName = $row['User_Name'];
    $UserAge = $row['User_Age'];
    $UserEmail = $row['User_Email'];
}

?>
```

there is the line code that is giving me error

```
<form action="update.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" 
placeholder=" User Name " name="name" value="<?php echo $UserName ?>">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" 
placeholder=" User Age " name="age"value="<?php echo $UserAge ?>">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control mb-2" 
placeholder=" User Email " name="email"value="<?php echo $UserEmail ?>">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" 
name="actualizar">Actualizar</button>
                    </form>
```

I'm missing something ?

Comment: Did you include the file?

Comment: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496)

Comment: Declare $UserName = ''; in the beginning.

Comment: How are the snippets related?

Comment: Declare all the variables used inside while loop as global like Aravind suggested

Comment: according @AravindBhatK I modified the fragment code but still with the same problem :(

Comment: As I can see, you have two different files. one is edit.php which has your HTML code and one is update.php which has your PHP code. So I hope you are including update.php in edit.php so that you can use defined variables in edit.php. Another way is to keep code in one file.

Comment: I found a solution was to change the command order "select * from user order by User_ID"